# Highcharts how to pass milliseconds to pointStart (really a javascript question)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What I am trying to do is pass a variable to the pointStart option of Highcharts.

Here's part of the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dtTemp = '1303401600000';
    // dtTemp is a DateTime in milliseconds
</script>
```

dtTemp is only for the purpose of this question assigned as above, it actually comes from the code-behind so using a variable as opposed to entering the number directly is a functional requirement.

What I would like to do is to use the dtTemp variable as my start point for a [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) series.  The appropriate way to do this is to assign dtTemp to [pointStart](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-spline--pointStart).  An example of pointStart in action can be seen in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Mmee/9).

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4],
    pointStart: dtTemp,    // DOES NOT WORK
    pointInterval: 3600000
}]
```

The code above does not work, Highcharts will not accept dtTemp as is.  I am pretty new to all of this but I assume the problem is that dtTemp is a string but it wants a number (double?).  However, replacing the above with the following does also not work:

```
pointStart: number(dtTemp),     // DOES NOT WORK EITHER
```

So I am just a bit at a loss now as to what the problem actually is.  Any insight you may be able to provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: SOLUTION as per mVChr reply:**

```
pointStart: Number(dtTemp),     // Number with a CAPITAL N works!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, but `Number(dtTemp)` needs to be capitalized.

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Mmee/6586/)

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I overlooked that!  Thank you SO much!